# GetCurrentDirectory() for SPA source path in startup.cs is returning a different path for VS2017 and VS Code

Tags: c#, node.js, visual-studio, asp.net-core, single-page-application

In my asp.NET core react application there's a place in startup.cs file where path for react source directory is defined.

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "ClientApp");
    spa.Options.SourcePath = path;
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
 });
```

---

And the whole `Startup.cs` and `Program.cs` file look like this

***`Program.cs`***

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
  CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
  WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
  .UseStartup < Startup > ();
```

***`Startup.cs`***

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
  Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration {
  get;
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
  services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

  // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
  services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration => {
    configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
  });
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
  if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
  } else {
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
  }

  //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
  app.UseStaticFiles();
  app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

  app.UseMvc(routes => {
    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "default",
      template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
  });

  app.UseSpa(spa =>
  {
    var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "ClientApp");
    spa.Options.SourcePath = path;
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
  });
 }
```

---

[image: VS 2017 Solution]

***VS 2017 Solution***

Using default `IIS Express` Configuration to start the debugging

[image: VS Code Folder]

***VS Code Folder***

Using default `.NET Core Launch (web)` configuration in `launch.json` to start the debugging

---

But in that case `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` returns a different path for **VS 2017** and **VSCode**. (This is expected probably because of the context).
The SPA source folder `ClientApp` resides in `SolutionFolder/Presentation/` along with `Startup.cs`, other necessary files and `Controllers` folder. `Presentation` is set as StartUp project.

How can I define that path relatively so it doesn't change depending on the IDE, environment or build?

Comment: Are you using 2.2? What's the difference between the two paths?

Comment: @KirkLarkin .NET Core 2.1. On VS 2017 --> `SolutionFolder/Presentation/` , VSCode--> `SolutionFolder/`

Comment: The distinction VS2017 vs VS Code is not so helpfull, how do you run this?  Also, post all relevant code form Startup and Main().

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have updated my post to include more information. See if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the issue I guess. Setting up as the startup project in **VS2017** sets the current working directory also to that path. Which gets reflected in the value of `CurrentRoothPath` or `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`.

But in **VSCode** with default debugging configuration, the current directory points to the root of the opened folder (not to any projects or child folder).

I had to change the value of `cwd` in `launch.json` from `"${workspaceFolder}"` to `"${workspaceFolder}/ReportingTool.Presentation"`

As per the docs:

> [**cwd** - current working directory for finding dependencies and other files](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging)

So I'm not entirely sure how this would affect the production build or other dependencies. This solves the issue for now. Hope, somebody will clarify further.